# Discord.py Rewrite - ASyncIO put() on queue not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Error Output

```
AttributeError: 'member_descriptor' object has no attribute 'put'
```

I currently have a MusicPlayer Class for my bot to play music the way I would like. I believe my command is causing the issue but I am not sure. I have never heard of a member_descriptor and upon looking it up there doesnt seem to be much on this error. I would like to just add songs to the queue and play them in that order, if their is no songs in the queue, it should just play it.

Below is my Class and Command. Any help is very appreciated!

**UPDATED**

**MusicPlayer Class**

````
class MusicPlayer():
    __slots__ = ("client", "_guild", "_ctxs", "_channel", "_cog", "np", "volume", "current", "colour", "task")
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    next = asyncio.Event()

    def __init__(self, ctx, client):

        self.client = client
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._ctxs = ctx
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.np = None
        self.volume = defaultvolume
        self.current = None
        self.colour = self.client.defaultcolour

        self.task = self.client.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

    async def player_loop(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()

        while True:
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                async with timeout(300):
                    self.current = await queue.get()
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                return
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                guild = self._guild
                vc = guild.voice_client
                self.destroy(guild)
                if not vc: return
                await self._ctxs.send(":point_right: **I disconnected myself from the **`{}`** voice channel as I was not playing audio for 5 minutes!**".format(vc.channel.name))
                return
            except:
                self.destroy(self._guild)
                await self._ctxs.send(":thumbsdown: **Error: getting next song failed!** Please retry later!")
                return

            self._ctxs.voice_client.play(self.current, after=lambda: self.client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(next.set))
            self.current.volume = self.volume
            thumbnail = self.current.thumbnail if self.current.thumbnail else self.client.user.avatar_url
            self.colour = await self.client.get_average_colour(thumbnail)
            embednps = discord.Embed(colour=self.colour)
            embednps.add_field(name="Now Playing", value=f"```{self.current.title}```", inline=False)
            embednps.add_field(name="Link", value=f"[URL]({self.current.web_url})", inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Duration", value=self.client.time_from_seconds(self.current.duration), inline=True)
            embednps.add_field(name="Channel", value=f"{self.current.uploader}", inline=False)
            embednps.set_thumbnail(url=f"{thumbnail}")
            embednps.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {self.current.requester}", icon_url=self.current.requester.avatar_url)
            self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embednps)

            await next.wait()
            print("Terminated")

            # Cleanup player
            self.current.cleanup()
            self.current = None

    async def add_song(self, player):
        return await self.queue.put(player)

    def destroy(self, guild):
        return self.client.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))
````

**Play Command**

```
    @commands.command(aliases=['yt', 'youtube'])
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url=None):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

        if url is None:
            await ctx.send("Music: Please specify a Youtube URL. Syntax (!play {URL})", delete_after=7)
            return

        if ctx.guild.voice_client is None:
            if not ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.send("Music: Please join a Voice Channel or use join command.", delete_after=7)
                return
            await channel.connect()
        else:
            if not ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.send("Music: Please join a Voice Channel or use join command.", delete_after=7)
                return
            if ctx.guild.voice_client.channel != ctx.message.author.voice.channel:
                await ctx.guild.voice_client.move_to(channel)

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.client.loop, stream=True)

            if ctx.guild.voice_client.is_playing():
                await MusicPlayer.add_song(MusicPlayer, player)
                await ctx.send('Music: {} has now been added to the Queue'.format(player.title), delete_after=7)
                return

            voice_channel = ctx.guild.voice_client
            voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda: self.client.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(MusicPlayer.next.set))
            await ctx.send('Music: Now playing {}'.format(player.title), delete_after=7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The class `MusicPlayer` has a descriptor `queue` that is created by `__slots__`. You're accessing that descriptor directly when you do `MusicPlayer.queue` instead of accessing an attribute of an instance, which you would do with `music_player.queue`.

At some point you need to create a `MusicPlayer` object from your class and use that instead of the class itself.

Comment: I dont think I fully understand what you mean. I updated the code in the question with what i have attempted to do in the past like 5 minutes. I dont understand where ```music_player``` is comming from.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now, I have updated the code. Instead of calling a class attribute I have now called a Instance Attribute. Now I have successfully ```put()``` the players in the queue but for some reason the class is not looping the way I would assume it should?